# MY ISP is not willing to route IP's using BGP how can I use my subnet/24

Tags: ip, mikrotik, bgp, static

I have a issue My ISP is not willing to set up BGP unless I use his Ip's , my question is how can i use my Subnet /24 anyways without my ISP is it even possible?

I have a Static IP, Mikrotik , I would really appreciate a solution if possible?

Comment: Unless you own an entire /24 address range, you can't. If you've got a regular SoHo ISP connection, they're unlikely to arrange anything professional like BGP for it. If you're willing to pay the price of a corporate connection, you have more possibilities. Are you sure this isn't an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info)? What's the exact issue you want to resolve with BGP?

Comment: Sir, I have a Business account by Deutsche Glassfaser but they will only do BGP when I use there IPS and they have high costs for more IPS but I will try to connect again with then to maybe find a salutation. Never know they might do it for a fee....

Comment: Dang, that's a bummer then. I hope you get the solution for a reasonable price.

Answer (score 1):

2 possibilities, first, use an external host with which you can setup BGP routes and tunnel it through to your own system. Second, find yourself a different ISP which is not so intransigent. The benefit of the first, is that if it comes under a DDOS, then you can switch the tunnel off, protect you & your isp, and still have your BGP session active

Comment: First Thanks for the reply.... my problem is of course that my ISP is the only that can supply a certain amount of speed in or Town (Germany) :-( which makes me his connection the only one which would come in Qeustion, or i have to change to a different one and will only get 6Mbit from telecom :-(

Robert

Answer (score 1):

If one ISP is not willing to announce your prefixes, then find another ISP that will agree to do that. (Or find the right person at the ISP to talk to; if you can afford a whole /24 then you probably can find a business contact.)

But if your direct ISP won't do BGP, it's not entirely uncommon to find a *remote* ISP which does – that is, announce the prefix at a nearby IX or datacenter, then tunnel everything to your location using GRE (or similar). Sometimes this involves setting up your own router at that remote location, sometimes you can run BGP directly from your location across the tunnel. (You will still access it *through* your local ISP, of course, but it doesn't need to offer anything special besides a static IP.)

It shouldn't be hard to find a commercial provider (carrier) who offers this service in Germany.

Comment: First Thanks for the reply.... my problem is of course that my ISP is the only that can supply a certain amount of speed in or Town (Germany) :-( which makes me his connection the only one which would come in Qeustion, or i have to change to a different one and will only get 6Mbit from telecom :-(

Robert

Comment: Well, in that case, you always have the option of announcing the prefix from elsewhere and GRE tunneling it to your location (or announcing it *via* the tunnel, depending on setup). For example, Hurricane Electric does BGP over GRE for a price – many hobbyists used to use their "free IPv6 BGP" tunnels back when those were still available. Plenty of such services with PoPs in Germany.